# Write batch file to copy folder based on user name

Tags: batch-file, environment-variables

I am learning how to use `xcopy` to copy a folder to a user's profile. The PC has multiple users therefore the batch file will need to get the username and then go into the folder structure inside the username.

EG: We have a PC with multiple users. Lets say one user is called User1 and one User2 need a folder located in `C:\FolderToCopy`

The FolderToCopy needs to be copied to `C:\Users\User1\AppData\NewFolderLocation` for user 1
and to `C:\Users\User2\AppData\NewFolderLocation` for user 2.

Can somebody help me in defining some sort of local variable where the user name is picked up based on who is logged in to the PC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just use the predefined variables:

```
%username%
%userprofile%
%localappdata%
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Just quick question. I found an environment variable called LOCALAPPDATA which takes me to C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local. How do I join the path to drill into Appdata\Local? I was thinking of doing it like this @set CopyFolderTo=%LOCALAPPDATA%\Temp\CopyToFolder. Is that the right way?

Comment: even quicker answer: yes.

Comment: Hi Stephan, Ok so  %LOCALAPPDATA%\Temp\CopyToFolder would be the same as writting C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\CopyToFolder . Correct?

Comment: Correct - that's why those environment variables exist.

Comment: Thanks Stefan. Just making sure as I tried this in my Batch but it didn't work so at least I know this is not the issue.

Comment: remove the `@` to see, what really happens.